# Azure Cosmos DB read change feed from date range

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

**Is it possible to query all historical change feed data from a specific datetime range?**

So far I've found [`ReadDocumentFeedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentfeedasync?view=azure-dotnet) which accepts a [`FeedOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions?view=azure-dotnet) object, but that object only allows for querying based on partition key ranges.

My main objective is knowing how to handle failures of my synchronization process.  Ideally I'd be able to set a date/time range to read from the change feed to synchronize any changes that occurred within that time.

Edit:  Reading from http://news.dataloco.com/working-with-the-change-feed-support-in-azure-documentdb-microsoft-docs, it appears you can set an "etag" to start from...  though I can't find support for it through C# classes and I have no idea if those API's still match that article.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, there is no way to setup a range. There is only StartTime property on the FeedOption.

Comment: I can't find the start time property.  Can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: Found it--it's part of CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery and ChangeFeedOptions.

Comment: Do you know if the order of documents retrieve is guaranteed to be oldest first?  If so, I could enforce the "end time" on the client side (simply stop fetching results)